# How to test non-Spring controllers using Spring test framework

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, spring-test, spring-test-mvc

Can anybody please provide me some guidance or code sample on how to do this?

## HomePageController.java

```
public class HomePageController extends HttpServlet {

    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(HomePageController.class);

    @Override
    public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
        super.init(config);
    }

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        log.debug("Into the HomePageController...");
        showPage(request, response, HOME_PAGE_URL);
    }

    private void showPage(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, String viewName) throws ServletException, IOException {
        log.debug("Displaying " + viewName + " page now...");
        String url = TEMPLATE_PAGE_URL + "?gotoPage=" + viewName;
        //forward the request to the page
        request.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(url).forward(request, response);
    }

}
```

Comment: What do you mean By SpringTestFramework?

Comment: Unit and integration testing using Spring framework

Comment: Is Mockito and Junit not enough to test HomePageController?

Comment: I have never used Mockito but I can try that for sure. Could you please provide me an example?

Comment: http://johannesbrodwall.com/2009/10/24/testing-servlets-with-mockito/